# Redirecting to webpage after web server restart

Tags: apache, redirect, sh, restart

I'm trying to have it so the user can restart the web server and instead of being taken to a web server not found page it will take the user back to the home page (placeholder is CNN). I can get the restart to work correctly however for some reason the restart isn't working when I redirect. The redirect will work by its self and so does the restart however if I have the redirect above the restart than only the redirect will happen if I have the restart above the redirect only the restart happens.

Is it even possible to be able to restart and web server then redirect? 
I'm working with Apache being hosted on a Raspberry Pi.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Restart"

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://www.cnn.com"/>

echo "</title></head><body>"


sudo service apache2 restart

retval=$?
error=$($2 2>&1 >/dev/stderr)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo  " Restart successful"
    echo "$1: $error"
else 
    echo "command failed, error number is $retval"
    echo "$1: $error"
fi
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What are you trying to do? Your script has errors, the `meta` line makes no sense.

Comment: I'm using Bash Shell CGI, founded the meta code here, https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/writing-a-cgi-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-6703/. All I want to do is restart the apache webserver then redirect back to that webserver's home page, I'm using cnn.com as a placeholder for that home page.